# Why is IP_MULTICAST_IF and IPV6_MULTICAST_IF needed?

Tags: windows, sockets, unix, networking, multicast

Say for example, my machine is multi-homed and has two network interfaces:

1. Wireless LAN adapter WiFi : Ip: 10.20.19.140
2. Ethernet adapter Ethernet: Ip: 10.20.19.154

I create two UDP sockets one listening on (1) and other on (2). The  i am assuming the interface is already assigned, then why do i need IP_MULTICAST_IF and IPV6_MULTICAST_IF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IP_MULTICAST_IF` or `IPV6_MULTICAST_IF` settings tell your socket which interface to *send* its multicast packets on.  It's a separate, independent setting from the interface that you bound your socket to with bind(), since bind() controls which interface(s) the socket *receives* multicast packets from.

(Granted, the BSD sockets API implementers could have made the assumption that a socket would always want to send packets out over the same interface it receives packets on, but that would make a number of use cases more difficult; for example, if you are using a single socket to receive multicast packets from all interfaces (via `INADDR_ANY`), then when sending a packet using that socket you'd still need a way to specify which multicast interface you want that packet to be sent over)

Comment: I like the assumption thing, sending a packet in that case could have had one of the 2 behaviors: 1. send on all interfaces 2. like today, send on the default interface.

Comment: I have one more question: Say, i bind both UDP socket to same local IP (10.20.19.154) and network interface but different ports (say, 9999 and 9000). Both the sockets have joined the same Group address: 237.132.100.17:9999. Then from first socket, if i send a multicast packet for the group address. Why is the second one not receiving it? When I change the second one's port to bind also to 9999, it works.

Comment: The multicast address (which does not include a port number) determines which computers the packet will go to.  Once the packet arrives at the computer, the tcp stack gives it to any sockets that are bound to the port specified by the packet's destination port field. (9999 in this case)